# Active MQ one message by a consumer

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

Can we configure ActiveMQ to send only one message per an instance of application  ?
Actually i have tomcat installed in a cluster mode.

I'm using Spring JMS template as consumer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain your question further; it's not clear what you are asking.

If you are talking about prefetch, IIRC ActiveMQ sets the prefetch to 1000 by default; set it to 0 to force messages to be distributed across all instances (at the cost of performance). Typically you will want to use prefetch, but you need to tune it for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Set the maxConcurrentConsumers property to 1.  This should make it so that only one thread consumes from the queue per node.